# How to loop through a list of elements and verify if one ends with a specific letter in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, ends-with

How would I go about looping through a list of elements and finding out whether the list ends with a specific letter?

My code keeps breaking on the `if` line saying stale element. Any suggestions?

My code is as follows:

```java
boolean ListEndsWithLetter(String column, String text) {
    List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@col-id='" + column + "']"));
    for (int i = 0; i < liElements.size(); i++) {
        if (liElements.get(i).getText().endsWith(text))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two main problems: (1) instead of `false` you should use `return false;`, (2) that `return false;` should be moved *after the loop*. Aside from that `return true` needs `;` after it.

Comment: Thanks I realized this after coping and pasting code here. Think I did come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing and it seems to be working:

```
boolean ListEndsWithLetter (String column, String text) {
    List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@col-id='" + column + "']"))
    for (int i = 0; i < liElements.size(); i++)
    {
        String j = liElements.get(i).getText()
        if (j.endsWith(text)) {
            return true
        }
        false
    }
}
```